# Vimeo pro/plus content with Duct Videos

Tags: plugin, security, video, vimeo

Is it possible to access videos in a Vimeo pro or plus account that have been flagged as private/domain restricted?

Comment: If your domain is listed in the Vimeo video settings, it still doesn't show up?

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I want to know that if I whitelist the domain in Vimeo. Would videos for the connected account show up in the Duct plugin.